# Navigation drawer + Action bar tabs design

Tags: android, tabs, navigation, drawer

In your opinion, what is the "best" design choice to implement a viewpager with two fragments that use swipe action when using the new navigation drawer pattern ? I tried tabs but navigation drawer doesn't overlap the action bar tabs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, Tabs is a sub level navigation. So, move it to navigations as sub level in a listview of Navigation Drawer

Answer (score 1):

From android guide:

More than 3 top-level views

Navigation drawers are great for displaying a large number of navigation targets concurrently. Use the navigation drawer if you have more than 3 unique top-level views. If not, use fixed tabs for top-level organization to ease discovery and interaction.

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: number one best answer give 10k stackoverflow points  to @talisaar plz <3